# Debug .NET app on kubernetes with ephemeral containers

Tags: .net, kubernetes, vscode-debugger

With vscode I want to debug a .NET core application inside a container running on kubernetes. To keep the image thin and lightweight there are no debug tools installed. Therefore I want to use the [Ephemeral Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/ephemeral-containers/) feature. The idea is to create a separate container with an image that includes vsdbg and run it alongside the app container.

I've done that with

`kubectl debug -it app-766688f87d-g49xk --image=debugimage:latest --share-processes --copy-to=app-debug`

I've managed to get dotnet-trace working by mounting the same shared /tmp folder to both containers. This is because dotnet-trace needs the same tmp folder as the process being traced. Not sure if that's the case for vsdbg.

My vscode launch.json looks like this

```
`{
      "name": "Kubernetes (Pod): .NET Core Attach in Kubernetes",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "attach",
      "processId": "${command:pickRemoteProcess}",
      "pipeTransport": {
        "pipeProgram": "kubectl",
        "pipeArgs": "exec -i app-debug -c debugger -- ${debuggerCommand}",
        "debuggerPath": "/opt/vsdbg/vsdbg",
        "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "quoteArgs": false
      },
      "sourceFileMap": {
        "/app": "${workspaceRoot}"
      }
    }`
```

The process picker works and I can select the right process, but after that this message appears:

`Unable to start debugging. Failed to attach to process: The .NET Debugger (vsdbg) has insufficient privileges to debug this process. To debug this process, vsdbg must be running with root permissions.`

The debug container runs as root, but the app container as www-data.

Is that even possible? I couldn't find any related documentation related to this.

Basically I want to debug the application without installing vsdbg on the image being debugged.